# Keras: LSTM Seq2Seq autoencoder input incompability error

Tags: keras, lstm, autoencoder

I'm trying to run the Seq2Seq example here, https://blog.keras.io/building-autoencoders-in-keras.html

```
from keras.layers import Input, LSTM, RepeatVector
from keras.models import Model

inputs = Input(shape=(timesteps, input_dim))
encoded = LSTM(latent_dim)(inputs)

decoded = RepeatVector(timesteps)(encoded)
decoded = LSTM(input_dim, return_sequences=True)(decoded)

sequence_autoencoder = Model(inputs, decoded)
encoder = Model(inputs, encoded)
```

My input is categorical encoding, e.g. [1, 23, 6, 12, 4, 0, 0, 0], which has 25 categories and fixed length of 1000.

So, the updated version of the code looks like:

```
    MInput = Input(shape=(MAX_LEN, CATEGORY_NUMS))
    encode_seq = LSTM(32)(MInput)

    decode_seq = RepeatVector(MAX_LEN)(encode_seq)
    decode_seq = LSTM(CATEGORY_NUMS, return_sequences=True)(decode_seq)

    autoencoder = Model(MInput, decode_seq)
    encoder = Model(MInput, encode_seq)
```

However, I'm getting " Input 0 is incompatible with layer lstm_2: expected ndim=3, found ndim=2" error.

Adding return_sequences=True to the first LSTM layer or removing the RepeatVector all give incompability error.

I'm not sure how else I have to prepare my input.

Thanks!

Comment: input shape should be (batch_size,timesteps,input_dim). Is the shape correct? did you mean MAX_LEN timesteps?

Comment: My input shape is max sequence length (MAX_LEN) and the number of unique characters in dictionary (CATEGORY_NUMS). I thought I could use MAX_LEN as time step but there was no reference to batch size?

Answer (score 1):

Your input X and output Y should be of the shape (batch_size,timesteps,input_dim). Try to print their shape and compare it with the model summary output shape.